# how to solve the onClick problem in typescript Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

my function is like this:

```
async function handleFavorites(event: MouseEvent) {
 event.preventDefault();
}
```

on my button, I'm using onclick to call this function but it's not working

```
<button
 type="submit"
 value={favorites}
 onChange={e => setFavorites(e.currentTarget.value)}
 onClick={() => { 
   handleFavorites();
 }}
>
```

Error: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
An argument for 'event' was not provided.

does anyone know how to solve? or have any tips?

Comment: `onClick={e =>  handleFavorites(e)}`?

Comment: already tried like this, there is a typing problem

Comment: Then there’s a problem with the function signature. It should probably take a `MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>`.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this? I have the exact same issue with the typescript event for a button click not having the target.value property

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are not passing the event argument to your handler. This should work:

```
<button
 type="submit"
 value={favorites}
 onChange={e => setFavorites(e.currentTarget.value)}
 onClick={handleFavorites}
>
```

Comment: already tried like this, there is a typing problem

Comment: In that case, `MouseEvent` is not the correct type. Usually typescript will tell you what type is expected. You could try: `MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>`, or `FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>`.

Answer (score 4):

React has its own ["synthetic events"](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) which wrap the underlying native DOM events.  The core of your problem is the confusion between the synthetic event and the native event.  Your `handleFavorites` method is currently expecting a native event, while the `button` `onClick` provides a synthetic event.  With your current types, you could actually do this `onClick={e => handleFavorites(e.nativeEvent)}`, though I don't recommend it.

Everyone else is correct that you want to pass your callback as `onClick={handleFavorites}`.  But in order to do that, your `handleFavorites` needs to accept a synthetic event.  React and the DOM both have their own interfaces for a `MouseEvent` with the same name, so you need to make sure that you are using the right one.

1. You can change the type to `(event: React.MouseEvent)` which makes it clear that this is react synthetic event.
2. You can keep `(event: MouseEvent)` and import the react version into your file `import React, {MouseEvent} from "react";`

Note that the native event and the synthetic event both have a `preventDefault()` method, so switching the type won't necessitate changes in the function.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write functions to onclick again.
Try it this way.

```js
function handleFavorites(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
}

onClick={handleFavorites}
```

Comment: I need to use FormEvent in the function, the typing problem

Answer (score 1):

`onClick={(e) => { handleFavorites(e); }}`

Or

`onClick={handleFavorites}`

Comment: already tried like this, there is a typing problem

Comment: Maybe from `event` type in the function. Try setting Its type to `any` instead of `MouseEvent`